# lxml on python-3.3.0 ImportError: undefined symbol: xmlBufContent

Tags: lxml, importerror, python-3.3

I am having a hard time installing lxml(3.1.0) on python-3.3.0. It installs without errors and I can see the lxml-3.1.0-py3.3-linux-i686.egg in the correct folder (/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/), but when I try to import etree, I get this:

> > > from lxml import etree
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/lxml-3.1.0-py3.3-linux-i686.egg/lxml/etree.cpython-33m.so: undefined symbol: xmlBufContent

I did try to install with apt-get, I tried "python3 setup.py install" and I did via easy_install. I have to mention that I have 3 versions installed (2.7, 3.2.3 and 3.3.0.), but I am too much of a beginner to tell if this has to do with it.

I did search all over, but I could not find any solution to this. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

best,
Uhru

Answer (score 1):

You should probably mention the specific operating system you're trying to install on, but I'll assume it's some form of Linux, perhaps Ubuntu or Debian since you mention apt-get.

The error message you mention is typical on `lxml` when the `libxml2` and/or `libxslt` libraries are not installed for it to link with. For whatever reason, the install procedure does not detect when these are not present and can give the sense the install has succeeded even though those dependencies are not satisfied.

If you issue `apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt libxslt-dev` that should eliminate this error.

Comment: Hi Scanny! thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried this on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I did install all the packages you mentioned, however with no success. As I did not manage to isntall on 3.3.0, I switched everything to 3.2 and installed it via aptitude. Somehow this was the best solution as I am a beginner :-)